# Jmeter extract data using BeanShell PreProcessor and add parameters

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Having the following request:

[image]

From this I extract using the Regular Expression Extractor the following string:

%5B1172%2C63%2C61%2C66%2C69%2C68%5D

I decode this using the urldecode function: ${__urldecode(${Groups_g2})}

Decoded: [1172,63,61,66,69,68]

On the following request I want to extract the values using the BeanShell PreProcessor to obtain a list of parameters like this one:

[image]

I know that I have to use sampler.addArgument but i can't figure how to extract data from the list and add the values as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Put `${__urldecode(${Groups_g2})}` into Beanshell PreProcessor's `Parameters` input field
2. Enter the following code into `Script` area

   ```
   String params = Parameters.substring(1, Parameters.length() - 1); // remove square brackets
   int counter = 1;
   for (String param : params.split(",")) { 
     sampler.addArgument("parameter" + counter, param);
     counter++;
   }
   ```

I have no idea what parameter names need to look like, hopefully above information will be helpful.

**HTTP Request with no parameters:**

[image: Empty HTTP Request]

**Beanshell PreProcessor**

[image: Beanshell PreProcessor]

**Parameters in [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)**

[image: Parameters in View Results Tree Listener]

For more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter check out H[ow to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.